# using jQuery mobile css in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, css, jquery-mobile

I am retrieving contacts of the phone using phone gap and want to display the names in listview by using jquery mobile. But the css is not being applied while executing this code

This is the code

```html
<!doctype html>
   <html>
      <head>

      <meta charset="UTF-8" />

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />

      <script src="cordova-1.5.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
      <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <script src="contact.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
      <script src="jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <script >
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
      function onDeviceReady() {

         var contactList = new ContactFindOptions(); 
         contactList.filter=""; 
         contactList.multiple=true;
         var fields = ["*"];  //"*" will return all contact fields
         navigator.contacts.find(fields,  getContactFields, onError, contactList );
         }

      function getContactFields(contacts) {
          //displaying contacts in list view
          for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++)
          {
              document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML+='<ul id="get" data-role="listview"><li><a href="#contact">'+contacts[i].displayName+'</a></li></ul>'
          }

          $('get').listview();
       }

       function onError(contactError) {
           alert('onError!');
       }
      </script>
```

This is the function I am using for displaying contact which is not applying the css

```
  //displaying contacts in list view
```

```js
 for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++)
 {
     document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML+='<ul id="get" data-role="listview"><li><a href="#contact">'+contacts[i].displayName+'</a></li></ul>'
 }

 $('get').listview();
```

Html body code where the contacts name to be displayed

```html
<div data-role="content" id="temp"></div>
```

Its displaying like in the following image. The css get applied to the first name only

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you have few errors in your code.

1. Your way of adding list elements is incorrect. You are adding listview for every element contact element. So first create ul element and then through loop add li elements into it. Also if you are using JQM use it with proper jQuery sintax.

Instead:

```
document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML+='<ul id="get" data-role="listview"><li><a href="#contact">'+contacts[i].displayName+'</a></li></ul>'
```

Use:

```
$('#temp').append(<ul id="get" data-role="listview"></ul>);
$('#temp ul#get').append('<li><a href="#contact">'+contacts[i].displayName+'</a</li>');
```

This is still not enough.

1. When listview is populated you must refresh its css like this:

   $('ul#get').listview('refresh');

You can find more info about this in the JQM [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html).

1. This statement is not going to do anything:

   $('get').listview();

You need to address it to the real ul element, and because get is its id it should look like this:

```
  $('#get').listview();
```